# enum vs static consts

Tags: c++, enums, c++03

I am currently thinking about the question if namespaced enums or namespaced groups of static consts are preferable.
What should be the default choice and why?

### Option 1:

```
namespace Direction
{
    enum Direction
    {
        north,
        east,
        south,
        west,
    };
}
```

### Option 2:

```
namespace Direction
{
    static const unsigned char north = 0;
    static const unsigned char east = 1;
    static const unsigned char south = 2;
    static const unsigned char west = 3;
}
```

Both have their advantages and disadvantages.

### Pro enum:

1. some typesafety:

   ```
   void foo(Direction dir); // the compiler won't allow you to just pass an int or a value of an unrelated enum without explicitly casting it
   ```

### Contra enum:

1. type safety is rather limited:

   ```
   enum A
   {
       Entry1 = 1
   };

   enum B
   {
       Entry2 = 10
   };

   A a;
   if(a == Entry2)
       ; // ouch!
   ```
2. no support for any other type than int - before C++ 11 one can't just have an enum of for example long long, short or char
3. the namespacing for enums is suboptimal

   1. if one doesn't wrap an enum into a separate namespace, then all its members will pollute the surrounding namespace.
   2. if one does wrap the enum into a separate namespace, then one gets some redundancy when using the enum itself as a type:
      One then has to declare a direction variable in the way Direction::Direction (when not doing a "using Direction::Direction", which would let them again pollute the outer namespace (at last in that part of the code, where the using directive takes effect)), to get able to namespace its members in the way Direction::north instead of just north

### Pro static const:

1. better type support in C++ prior to C++ 11 - one can for example use types like unsigned char for the constants
2. proper scoping - no pollution of the outer namespace, without explicitly asking for it via a using directive (and even then only in a limited scope)

### Contra static const:

1. even less type safety than enums - one is no longer able to declare a function prototype like this:

   ```
   void foo(Direction dir);
   ```

   but would have to do it in the following way:

   ```
   void foo(unsigned char dir); // now each variable of type unsigned char or of a type that can implicitly be casted into unsigned char can be passed, even if its totally unrelated to the expected "enumeration" or if the value does not match the value of any of the expected consts
   ```

**EDIT:**
Here I have found an interesting article about limitation in the type safety of enums:
http://www.drdobbs.com/enumerations/184401797

Comment: enums are meant for this purpose, they take up no memory(if they are not used), and the take way less typing

Comment: In your second example, what is `north` assigned to? With an `enum` you can go with default values, or you can specify which constant value should be used. The type-checking alone is worth it. Don't do the alternative.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the question. If you are *enumerating* things (like cardinal directions) and you are supposed to have "type safety", then go with `enum`s. `static` variables are meant for a whole other range of problems.

Comment: @aaronman: afaik a static const only takes up memory if its address gets referenced, otherwise it does not take any memory even if it is used.

Comment: *"no support for any other type than int - before C++ 11 [...]"* An enum (even in C++03) is a distinct type with an unspecified underlying type -- this underlying type doesn't have to be `int` [dcl.enum]/5: "The *underlying type* of an enumeration is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values
defined in the enumeration. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type
for an enumeration except that the underlying type shall not be larger than `int` unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an `int` or `unsigned int`."

Comment: Question [on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979624/best-practice-on-writing-constant-parameters-for-embedded-systems) but about C. I wrote an answer there trying to list the differences between `const`, `#define` and `enum` constants. But of course C++ is a different beast, since it has better type safety and indeed namespaces.

Comment: @dyp But at least in C, an enumeration constant is however guaranteed to be of type `int`. So there is an inconsistency in the C standard: you can declare an enumerated type which has impl.defined size, but you can only use it to store constants that are of the same size as int. One of many cases where the C language is completely irrational...

Answer (score 2):

The big difference is the typing.  The enum has a distinct type;
the static const must have an existing integral type (although
it can be used elsewhere).  Which one is preferable depends on
what you want: in the case of `Direction`, you probably want
a unique type, and the enum is preferable.  In other cases, what
you really want is a named constant with an integral type, say
as the dimension of an array.  In those cases, static const is
probably preferable.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 [solves](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c19083/C-2011-Stronglytyped-Enums.htm) all of the contra enum points by means of strongly typed enums and improved scoping.

For a fixed set of values like your example of cardinal directions, I'd use enum.

Comment: Care to explain this in more detail? Are C++11 enums guaranteed to be of a certain integer size? Are enumerated types and enumerated constants guaranteed to be of the same type? If so, that would be a much-needed major improvement of enums. At least in C11, enums are still as obscure as ever.

Answer (score 1):

With enums you can tie all constants which belongs to a concept together (with a unique c++ identifier named `enum`).

Herb Sutter wrote about prefering new style casts (`static_cast`) instead of C casts. One of his arguments (among others) was that they can be found with a regular expression in source code.

Back to your question it means if you take `enum` you can grep through you code base to find occurrences of constants which are meant to be used together. This is not possible with constants in a namespace.